# Rendering thickness of plastic

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency

Recently I was rendering a box for a circuit board that I am working on. The box has a lid out of plastic that is fully transparent on the top but blurry on the sides. The following image shows a photo of the original box. The 3D model I used is from the box manufacturer (https://www.fibox.com/catalog/61/product/171/6016908_ENG3.html).
[image: Photo of box]

When trying to render the lid, I was not able to get the thickness of the plastic right, especially in the corners and edges were it looks solid. Here is my rendered image (cycles).
[image: Rendered image of box]

What is the best way to get the lid right?

I have little experience with shading so any guideance in the right direction would be great. Following is an image of the material I created for the blurry plastic.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristics of the plastic lid are more like glass so the solution was to use Glass BSDF shader instead of Principled BSDF. That with Principled Volume and the lid looks amazing.

The following image shows the result.
[image]
Removing hard edges on the model was necessary to eliminate darkness in round corners as pointed out by @spiffyJon.

Here is the shader setup:
[image]

There is one small error that still needs attention and that is the strange line in the top corner. It should be dark and solid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the area I highlighted here being too dark? If so, try adjusting IOR in the Principled BSDF.

[image: box]

Comment: Yes that is one of the thing I need to fix. I did work a bit on the faces of the model and removed the hard edges on the rounded corners and that seems to have fixed it. The top corners of the lid should show dark streaks similar to the ones shown on the original photograph. The problem is they only appear when watching the lid under a certain angle. If looking at the photograph, the corner to the left has a dark line in it, the one facing the camera does not.